# Is using "while" instead of "whereas" discouraged in academic writing?

Tags: word-choice, style, formality

Some time ago, I was participating in a course for academic paper writing in which the professor cautioned the students against using *while* instead of *whereas*. It was surprising for me; I supposed that it is a completely acceptable point in English.

Is it really recommended in academic writing to use *whereas* rather than *while*?

Comment: *Whereas* is the more formal choice there. It isn't pretentious.

Comment: @TRomano The pretentious-writing tag was my bad. I guess I got a little overzealous when I was adding tags. The only pretension is the OP's teacher insisting that *while* is not "good enough" for academic writing. *Whereas* is a perfectly fine and useful word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both *while* and *whereas* are perfectly fine in academic writing. The important thing to remember, is that *while* has another meaning relating to time. It says that one action takes place at the same time as another. If you aren't careful, it can sometimes be ambiguous as to which meaning is intended:

- While Obama introduced Medicaid, Bush started two wars.

Here the sentence could mislead the reader for a second, because it sounds as if Obama and Bush were doing these things at the same time. If there is any chance of being misunderstood or making your sentence a bit more difficult to understand, don't use *while* or *whilst*.

Comment: I have thought *IT* was *informatuion technology*