# Whereas vs while to link contrasting statements

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, conjunctions

Is there any effective difference between *while* and *whereas* when used to link contrasting statements, or are differences in usage only a matter of style rather than grammar? See the following sentences as an example.

- John likes blue cars, *whereas* Tom prefers red ones.
- John likes blue cars, *while* Tom prefers red ones.

Comment: They can be used interchangeably, but **whereas** is often considered **more formal.**

Comment: @goshawk, it’s preferred if users search before asking questions. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235618/should-i-use-whereas-or-while-in-this-sentence)

Comment: @Sam: They're both relatively formal (but neither so much as ***whilst***). The "normal / informal" conjunction is either ***but*** or ***and***, depending on whether the speaker wishes to call attention to the difference / contrast or simply illustrate the range of preferences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using "while" instead of "whereas" discouraged in academic writing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53442/is-using-while-instead-of-whereas-discouraged-in-academic-writing) See also [Should I use "whereas" or "while" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235618/should-i-use-whereas-or-while-in-this-sentence)